# What is a viable alternative for a Dictionary for Search applications in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

My situation is as following:

I have a huge CSV file with about 300 thousand entries which I converted into a Dictionary in Swift with the CSVImporter Framework.
The User now can enter a key into the App and it will print out the Value. Sadly before that all works the App has to load the whole dictionary which is around 800MB into the RAM, that sometimes takes  around 1-2 minutes before a search can happen. After loading a search happens fast.

The code looks like this:

```
var stack = [String: String]()

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MASTERKopie", ofType: "csv")!

importer.startImportingRecords { $0 }.onFinish { importedRecords in
        for record in importedRecords {
            stack[record[0]] = record[2]
        }
```

If I would use SQLite, how do I convert my Dictionary to a Database/Table?

Comment: You need a database, not a dictionary. That's way too much data to load into memory at once.

Comment: @rmaddy can a Database be inside the App? My Goal is it to be able to Search offline

Comment: Sure. Use SQLite (or Core Data).

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks! I revised my Question to be more precise.

Comment: CSV is a very uncomfortable format anyway. There is no clear specification so the parser must detect all different appearances which is quite expensive. On the other hand JSON or property list is much more standardized.

Comment: “f I would use SQLite, how do I convert my Dictionary to a Database/Table?” You wouldn’t. You would start with the database already embedded in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your computer, quite outside of your app, write a script or app that recodes your big data as a SQLite database. Include that database in your app. Now when the app runs the data is available instantly via SQLIte with no time spent converting and no strain on memory (because data fetches are performed from disk as needed).